# Android Document tell us the max number of devices that adb can detect is 16 But I found that is wrong

Tags: android, adb

I connect 45 devices to my computer, and the adb can detect them.

But I see the description below means that a computer can only detect 16 devices。 Can somebody help me?

[enter link description here](https://developer.android.com/studio/command-line/adb.html#howadbworks)

> The server then sets up connections to all running devices. It locates emulators by scanning odd-numbered ports in the range 5555 to 5585, the range used by the first 16 emulators. Where the server finds an adb daemon (adbd), it sets up a connection to that port. Note that each emulator uses a pair of sequential ports — an even-numbered port for console connections and an odd-numbered port for adb connections.

Answer (score 0):

All that is about `emulators`, can't you see? not about real devices.
Number of emulators is limited because of limit of ports used to connect ADB to emulators. Physical devices don't use ports for connection.

Comment: I seriously read the document again and found it described as you said.

Comment: But in the old document, because contains / device, so I mistakenly think that the real machine is also limited  [link](https://stuff.mit.edu/afs/sipb/project/android/docs/tools/help/adb.html)

Comment: @Kevin, you *can* use ports for real devices, when you connect them wireless to ADB over WIFI for example. This way you can connect up to 16 devices + emulators (over wireless network)

Comment: Do you means that “adb tcpip 555 &&&& adb connect {ip}:5555”?

Comment: @Kevin, yes, like that.

Comment: I execute the command `netstat -nat | grep 100.84.35.61 (my computer's ip)`, the result is `tcp 0 0 100.84.35.61:57916 100.84.35.61:2377 ESTABLISHED`, found that it is not monitoring between 5555 and 5585 Odd port