# Why did ADB suddenly stopped detecting more than 15 devices concurrently?

Tags: android, adb

I was able to connect more than 15 devices via `adb` concurrently(over `tcpip`) but now I am finding I am no longer able to to connect more than 15. What went wrong how can I go back to previous state ?
Even though there are documentation of allowing only 15 devices I guess those hold from emulators but for physical devices it was working fine for more than 15 [Android Document tell us the max number of devices that adb can detect is 16 But I found that is wrong](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45159600/android-document-tell-us-the-max-number-of-devices-that-adb-can-detect-is-16-but)

Comment: If this is happened becase of os update and if 7 days are not complete till this date, You can go to settings -> Update & Security ->  Windows Update -> View update history and then click "Uninstall updates". This will uninstall the recent updates and will solve the issues you got after updating OS.

Comment: didnt work tried, so update may not be the cause

Comment: That means this may not happened because of the update. I will suggest you to uninstall the adb drivers and reinstall the adb drivers. Or you can add path to the google adb drivers present in your sdk folder. Generally this is the path of the adb drivers of google. `C:\Users\UserName\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\platform-tools`

Comment: tried didn't help. By some fluke it might have been working earlier, I guess 15 max is expected design. https://www.reddit.com/r/androiddev/comments/1h98hp/adb_15_device_limit/?utm_source=share&utm_medium=web2x&context=3

Comment: It seems like we have to increase `ADB_LOCAL_TRANSPORT_MAX`  and rebuild adb.

Comment: ofcourse standard adb has the limit of 15. This post suggests the same. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46596025/how-to-start-more-than-16-android-emulators.

Comment: https://github.com/bonnyfone/adb-arm, https://forum.xda-developers.com/t/q-rebuilding-adb-exe-for-windows.2888237/ These links may help you.

Comment: @anirudhdhsinh-jadeja I don't have so much free hard disk nor am I on linux to be able to setup `aosp`. :'(  Bro if are you actively developing android It would be great if you can do this favor for me by building `adb` with ADB_LOCAL_TRANSPORT_MAX=128. If you need any other favor in return I would be happy to help.

Comment: Well, I am too. And I didn't even know that there is ADB_LOCAL_TRANSPORT_MAX variable which can increase the devices. I simply searched your given info and I got these links. Honestly, I don't even understand what's going on in the xda link. But, still if you need other help in developing android apps, I may be able to help there. As newbie i won't be a much of help but, sure can try to help.

Comment: Sure we are all newbies and we are all super experts once we have done that thing once. My restriction is not ability to learn, the restriction is currently I don't have enough memory to setup `aosp` on this PC. Let me go through the docs again to understand if it's possible to build without setting up full `aosp` ie if somehow we could just do it by just setting up `repo` and `git` on a virtualbox I might be able to. Meanwhile since you are playing with android if you manage to compile `adb` from source please do reply on this thread.

Comment: Sure. I will try my best. Best of luck

Comment: @anirudhdhsinh-jadeja In case you need I am trying this https://www.mancoosi.org/~abate/build-android-adb-debian-sid-amd64.html , its very old but conceptually may be on right track.

Comment: Actually the issue is not with limit of 15 . I just managed to connect 22 devices without any change to adb binaries. After 22 it stopped sensing the 23rd and all onwards but I realized whenever it stops detecting further devices it initiates with this error https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68152529/power-surge-on-the-usb-port-unknown-usb-device-needs-more-power-than-the-port

Comment: This can be easily avoided by using wifi adb

Comment: You didn't get the point, all my devices are connected via wifi only, were you imagining a PC with hundreds of USB port ? :D But to setup tcpip I have to connect every device to PC one by one. It was failing on 16th connection , once I skipped that device it started accepting more devices and again failed on 23rd device.

Comment: Are the devices connected to a USB hub with an external power supply? I noticed you also posted a question about USB port not being able to supply enough power, so I'm assuming that is the issue https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68152529/power-surge-on-the-usb-port-unknown-usb-device-needs-more-power-than-the-port

Comment: no usb hub. no external power supply. only one device at a time  and that is directly to PC